# Build Solution in Visual Studio 2015 gives error "Error generating Win32 resource: Access is denied"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build

I'm getting weird error building the solution using Visual Studio 2015.
Error is attached:

```
7>(0,0): error CS1567: Error generating Win32 resource: Access is denied. 
7>(0,0): warning CS1610: Unable to delete temporary file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4b1e3fb3\c485404e\CSC4CF967AFEF7848B58432AE4797C64B6E.TMP' used for default Win32 resource -- The system cannot find the file specified. 
7>Validation Complete
```

[image]

What error is this and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by giving myself write access to that folder `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`.

Also, if the application is 64-bit, I need to grant access to `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`. as well.

Answer (score 0):

its working fine after giving full authority to the current user for the folder
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files.

Comment: That's really odd. Do you have custom permissions on your drive? Were you using Windows Authentication on your web application? Or were you otherwise impersonating a custom identity? By default, `IIS_IUSRS` has the appropriate permissions on that directory. Given that, my immediate question would be whether your current user was part of `IIS_IUSRS`—or if something got messed up with your folder permissions.